# How get words into a JS Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

I got a handful of words from `Cookies.get`, separated by commas. Like this: `apple,pineapple,tomato`  How can I put these words into an array?

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `.split`: `"my,awesome,string".split(",")` -> `["my", "awesome", "string]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method. Ex. `words.split(",")`. Documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).